# Using Momentary Tracking with NSSegmentedControl

Tags: cocoa, nssegmentedcontrol

The documentation for NSSegmentedControl says the following about using NSSegmentSwitchTrackingMomentary mode:

> A momentary segmented control sends an action when the user clicks a
>   segment, and another action when the user releases the segment. If
>   configured as continuous (see setContinuous:), the control also sends
>   actions at repeating intervals until the user releases the segment, at
>   which point the control sends its final action.
>
> When the user clicks a segment, the selectedSegment value is the index
>   of the active segment. When the user releases the segment, the
>   selectedSegment value is -1.

However, this is not the behaviour I see... unless I am misunderstanding what Apple means by "clicking" and "releasing" a segment.

I would expect, from that description, that when the user presses the mouse button over a segment the action would be called, and upon releasing the mouse button the second action is sent.

However, I only ever see a single action, when the mouse button is released. Additionally, if I enable continuous mode I still also only receive the singe action upon releasing the mouse button.

The documentation states this functionality is available from OSX 10.3 and higher, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: The post is quite old, but did you manage to find an explanation of the described behavior?

Comment: @IvayloNikolov I honestly do not recall given the age of the post. If I recall the project this question pertained to I will check and let you know. These days I have been playing with Lua and AHK far more than ObjC, sorry! :)